# Should all the items be entered in a PCA at the same time?

Tags: pca, factor-analysis

Assume that a few items will load together on one component if only these 3-4 items were entered in a separate PCA. However, if these 3-4 items are entered in the main PCA (where like 15-20 are being grouped together), these 3-4 which clearly represent a different construct will cross-load on the components of the main intended construct (the one with 15-20 items). In that case, can one ran separate PCAs for separate constructs? Will the components score remain valid if entered as a dependent variable later on?

Comment: Depending on what your scientific hypothesis is you might consider confirmatory factor analysis which would let you specify a model which you could then test.

Comment: But problem is that, on CFA, all indices look good except the model fit is significant! Can one continue based on that? If yes, should one get back to EFA to 'confirm' the 'confirmed pattern'?